# How to get all User Profile Claims of a user in Wso2 Identity server

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a question relating to get all profiles ( email, phone, address ) after logging successfully in WSO2 Identity Server.

After login, we can have cookie(sessionID) and then based on this, we can use UserStoreManager to get roles, list user, profiles... and as mentioned in the below link.

I can get use function to get profiles getProfileNames() but the result when I call is only ["default"] while I inputted my email, phone, address, etc in userprofile section in console.

I appreciate your help in this case. 
Hope that you can help me. Thanks

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so what you are trying to achieve is to get claim values(email, phone etc.) of a user.

for this, you can use the getUserClaimValue()[1] or getUserClaimValuesForClaims()[2]

Both these method take in three arguments,

1. Username of user
2. Claim name / Claim names you are trying to retrieve (email, gender etc.)
3. Profile name (you can pass null, then values from default profile will return)

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-getUserClaimValue()

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-getUserClaimValuesForClaims()

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will try and feedback again to y soon

Comment: oh. It's ok . Thank y so much

Comment: + farasath : can I ask y an additional question ? 
We can have api to check valid/invalid session( cookie) or not ?

Comment: Can you ask a new StackOverflow question for that? That will be useful for anyone who has the same question to search :)